# Not creating a new instance of NSMutableDictionary when passing to another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutabledictionary

i have an NSMutableDictionary declared in a class but i want to print get access to the contents of it in another class for example

```
@interface MyClass0 : NSObject
{

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *valuee;
@end
```

and in implementation i do

```
@implementation MyClass0

- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];

[valuee setObject:@"name" forKey:@"Aryan"];

}

@end
```

Now i create a new class called MyClass1 where i want to access these

```
  @interface MyClass1 : NSObject
    {
    }

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *dict;

    @end
```

and the implementation

```
@implementation MyClass1
@synthesize dict;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];

 self.dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 MyClass0 *c = [[MyClass0 alloc] init];

 self.dict = c.valuee;

  // dict is not nil but the contents inside is nil so it clearly creates a new instance


}

@end
```

Comment: You are allocing and initing you MyClass0 but it's view is not being loaded so nothing is getting set in its dictionary. On the other hand you have specified copy for your dict property so, yes, it is creating a copy.

Comment: i put copy by accident i will edit the question :) @Remover

Comment: I just tried what you said Thanks :) @Remover

Comment: *"it clearly creates a new instance"* - **no**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the instance of `MyClass0` and `valuee` is declared but not initialized.

The closest solution to your code is

```
MyClass0 *c = [[MyClass0 alloc] init];
c.valuee = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

self.dict = c.valuee;
```

If a value is assigned to a declared property then an explicit initialization is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a simple NSMutableDictionary that has the same contents every time you can create a class method in MyClass0 like so:

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *) getDict {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:@"name" forKey:@"Aryan"];//did you mean [dict setObject:@"Aryan" forKey:@"name"]?
    return dict;
}
```

To access this, declare the method in the MyClass0.h file like so: `+ (NSMutableDictionary *) getDict;` and simply call `[MyClass0 getDict];` in your MyClass1.m file.

If it doesn't have the same contents every time, you'll have to pass the dictionary forward to each view controller in prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this next line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {

        MyClass1 *mc = [segue destinationViewController];
        mc.dict = self.valuee;
    }
}
```